# create-react-native-app : The term 'create-react-native-app' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react naitive and when i am trying to create this app i am getting this error

PS F:\newton\react-native> create-react-native-app task

create-react-native-app : The term 'create-react-native-app' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ create-react-native-app task
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (create-react-native-app:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

please let me know what should i do to remove this error

Comment: Try npx create-react-native-app

Comment: once I run this command it react all modules but after that i need to run the projcet using react-native run-andriod so it says this is not a recognized command

Answer (score 0):

For Create a new app in react native you can also use

```
react-native init appname
```

You can use the above command to create the react native app.

Comment: When i do this it says react-native is not a recognized cmd or a function. so this is not resolvable for me

Comment: you need to install the react native first then this command will work